# Scroll page to the bottom of a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some really large `div`s with code samples and I'd like to add a button so, when the user clicks on it, the page will scroll (with some ease) to the bottom of that `div`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.story {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="story">
  <button class="scrollToBottom">Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button class="scrollToBottom">Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button class="scrollToBottom">Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
<div class="story">
  <button>Scroll to bottom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set `scrollTop` to `scrollHeight`.

```
elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
```

If you have an element you want to scroll to, call `scrollIntoView()` on a reference to it.